# how to wait for a function to complete its execution in angular 6 before executing the following code execution?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a two functions as below:

```
refreshAccessToken() {
  let rt = this.injector.get(LocalStorageService);
  var tokenData = rt.getAuthorizationData();
  var refreshToken = tokenData.refresh_token;
  var refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('userRefreshToken');
  if (refreshToken !== null) {
    var data = "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refreshToken;
    var basicAuth = btoa("crmClient1:crmSuperSecret");
    var headerData = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + basicAuth,
      "No-Auth": "True",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    };
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders(headerData);
    this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, data, {
        headers: reqHeader
      })
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.localStorageService.setAuthorizationData(response);
        console.log("I need to be called first");
      });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

getNewAccessToken(): Observable < string > {
  this.refreshAccessToken();
  console.log("I need to be called as a second value");
  var varTokenData = this.localStorageService.getAuthorizationData();
  var newAccessToken = varTokenData.access_token;
  this.newat = newAccessToken;
  return of(this.newat);
}
```

I am calling `refreshAccessToken()` function inside `getNewAccessToken()` function. Here, the code is doing fine except that the codes:

```
console.log("I need to be called as a second value");
var varTokenData = this.localStorageService.getAuthorizationData();
var newAccessToken = varTokenData.access_token;
this.newat = newAccessToken;
return of(this.newat);
```

are executed before the complete execution of function `refreshAccessToken()`. How do I make other codes wait for execution until the `refreshAccessToken()` function is completely executed in angular 6?

The error I am getting is as below:

[image]

The section of AuthInterceptor from where I a calling getNewAccessToken() function is as below:

//generating new token from refresh_token

```
handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    console.log("Error 401 called");
    if (!this.isRefreshingToken) {
        this.isRefreshingToken = true;

        // Reset here so that the following requests wait until the token
        // comes back from the refreshToken call.
        this.tokenSubject.next(null);
        return this.loginService.getNewAccessToken()
        .pipe(
            switchMap((newToken: string) => {
                if (newToken) {
                    this.tokenSubject.next(newToken);
                    //this.isRefreshingToken=false;
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(req, newToken));
                }

                // If we don't get a new token, we are in trouble so logout.
                //this.isRefreshingToken=false;
                return this.logout();
            }),
            catchError(error => {
                // If there is an exception calling 'refreshToken', bad news so logout.
                //this.isRefreshingToken=false;
                //console.log(error);
                return this.logout();
            })
        //)

        ),
        finalize(()=>{
            this.isRefreshingToken=false;
        });   
    } else {
        return this.tokenSubject
            .pipe(
                filter(token => token !=null)
            ),
            take(1),
            switchMap((token: string )=> {
                return next.handle(this.addToken(req,token));
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use async and await for this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can u guide me, how can i implement async and await for this? I would be grateful.

Comment: Take a look: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/async-await.html

Answer (score 5):

You can `return` an `Observable` from your `refreshAccessToken` method:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

refreshAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
  ...
  if (refreshToken !== null) {
    ...
    return this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, data, {
      headers: reqHeader
    })
    .pipe(tap(response => this.localStorageService.setAuthorizationData(response)));
  } else {
    return of(null);
  }
}
```

And then subscribe to it from your `getNewAccessToken` method like this:

```
getNewAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
  this.refreshAccessToken()
    .subscribe(response => {
      ...
    });
}
```

**Alternatively:**

You could use `async`/`await` which were introduced in ES2017. Since they work only with functions dealing with `promise`s and not `Observable`s, you will have to change your functions a bit to return a `promise` instead of `Observable`.

Here's how:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

refreshAccessToken() {
  ...
  if (refreshToken !== null) {
    ...
    return this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, data, {
      headers: reqHeader
    })
    .pipe(tap(response => this.localStorageService.setAuthorizationData(response)))
    .toPromise();
  } else {
    return of(null).toPromise();
  }
}
```

And then declare `getNewAccessToken`as `async` and `await` `refreshAccessToken`:

```
async getNewAccessToken() {
  await this.refreshAccessToken();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";

async ngOnInit() {
  let data = await this.getDataFromMultipleApis();
  console.log(data);
}
getDataFromMultipleApis(){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      forkJoin(
        this.Service.api1(),
        this.Service.api2()
      ).subscribe(docs => {        
        resolve(docs);
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage TypeScript's [async/await](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html) pattern  if you convert the `Observable` objects to `Promise`s. Then you can write code that looks more synchronous. It's worth calling out, however, that the code itself is still using callbacks and Promises to actually execute, but that's abstracted away from you by the syntactic sugar.

```
async getNewAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
    // Your refreshAccessToken() needs to always return an Observable now.
    await this.refreshAccessToken().toPromise();
    console.log("I need to be called as a second value");
    var varTokenData = this.localStorageService.getAuthorizationData();
    var newAccessToken = varTokenData.access_token;
    this.newat = newAccessToken;
    return this.newat;
}
```

Comment: Now I got an error like this:
ERROR in src/app/pagecomponents/utilities/AuthInterceptor.ts(80,14): error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<string>>'.

Comment: I have updated my question with the section of AuthInterceptor from where I am calling getNewAccessToken() function.

Comment: That's because an `async` method (in this case `getNewAccessToken()`) returns a promise, not an observable. `pipe` is a method on an observable.